# Convert python code to php

Tags: php, python, json

I found solution of my task on python. But I do not know python at all. Code:

```
import re
import json
a = open('test.txt').read()
a = re.sub('"[ \t]*"', '":"', a)
a = re.sub('"\s+"', '","', a)
a = re.sub('"\s+{', '":{', a)
a = re.sub('}\s+"', '},"', a)
a = '{%s}' % a
b = json.loads(a)
```

Tried to convert it to php by analogy:

```
$a = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$a = preg_replace('"[ \t]*"', '":"', $a);
$a = preg_replace('"\s+"', '","', $a);
$a = preg_replace('"\s+{', '":{', $a);
$a = preg_replace('}\s+"', '},"', $a);
$a = '{'.$a.'}';
$b = json_decode($a);
```

But seems like expressions are wrong. Can someone help with it?

Comment: Add debug print statement after each of the replacement operations and check for differences...

Comment: Patterns in `preg_replace` are enclosed with slashes

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for preg_replace() and PCRE expressions

I doubt you can literally put the expressions that your Python was using, straight into the preg_replace() function unless they use the same standard for REGEX.

Comment: @Ander2 They can be enclosed by any two non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace characters, not just slashes: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Although I admit it's weird, OP is using double quotes (`"`) as delimeters, which work fine.

Comment: @AndréDion you're right, anyway he is missing delimiters in some patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP I think regular expressions need to be inside 2 x `/` e.g.

```
$a = preg_replace('/"[ \t]*"/', '":"', $a);
```

Edit: As André mentioned, the delimiter does not necessarily need to be forward slashes, however I think the double quotes you're using are meant to be used as part of the regular expression rather than the delimiters.

Comment: OP is using double quotes to delimit his regular expressions, which [is valid](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: That's true, but I think the OP was possibly trying to search for the double quotes rather than use them as delimiters.